What happens when std::future is reassigned without wait?
The function below was designed to run a lambda on an async one time after transactions started occurring in a scenario where the transactions will continue periodically.
Every completed transaction calls this function, which should only launch an async the first time the function is called.
Later, the reset was added so that the function could be "re-armed" if the transactions stopped due to some failure.  Then if/when the transactions start again, this function should run the async lambda again.
void first_trans(bool reset = false){
    static bool ran_once{false};
    static std::future<void> fut;

    if(reset) {
        ran_once = false;
        return;
    }
  
    if(!ran_once){
        ran_once = true;
    
        // DO I NEED TO WAIT BEFORE THIS ASSIGNMENT
        // ON SUBSEQUENT ENTRIES TO THIS BLOCK?

        fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [=] {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}

According to the following question:
Can you reuse a std::future once it has already been assigned to std::async()?
The documentation on the future assignment operator states:

Assigns the contents of another future object.

Releases any shared state and move-assigns the contents of other to *this. After the
assignment, other.valid() == false and this->valid() will yield the
same value as other.valid() before the assignment.


I was assuming initially that upon assignment, the destructor for the current future would be called, which would wait on the future then destruct, then the assignment would take place.  I am not clear now because of the terminology "Releases any shared state".
Questions:

Must I wait on the future before the assignment, or will the code function properly as-is without overlapping or leaking?
What happens to the "Released" state?


Your code has a data race with ran_once as multiple threads could access it at the same time.

Instead of your bool ran_once, take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once

@NathanOliver - does std::atomic_bool fix the data race?

@ttemple it should.

It will solve the race condition on ran_once, technically. But the compare and mutation are not mutually atomic. For example, multiple threads might see ran_once as false at the same time before any of them reaches their ran_once = true;, leading to multiple executions of the branch concurrently. This now introduces a race on fut.

@FrançoisAndrieux - Understood.  In my case one and only one thread calls this function, so I am not so concerned about concurrency issues.
